# Ajax File Upload with valum' Ajax Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am looking at using  Valum's Ajax File Upload.
(**Note:** *I realize that this version is probably outdated & replaced by the later "Fine Updater" but this is much too complex for me !!!* ), and would like to have more than one instance of an upload button on the same form.

I'm having issues with the code markup here so I've posted the 2 examples / Tests for the 2 upload button IDs :

[Here](http://jmbdev.com/test/test_upload2.php) for the one that DOESN'T work, and [here](http://jmbdev.com/test/test_upload3.php) for the one which correctly uploads & displays the uploaded resized image.

The JS & HTML are obviously viewable from your browser, sorry for my 'blockquote' shortcomings !

Many thanks for your help

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: Rocket Hazmat,thanks for reading me.
My question is : I have the 2 instances of AjaxUpload together in my script, but only one, the first, works, and I don't understand why...
A JS scripting error, logical error , or something to do with th eplugin in itself ( iframe related stuff ?) ?

Comment: Check your JavaScript on the one that doesn't work.  It looks like you just copied & pasted the code.  `new AjaxUpload('#section4',` won't work on that page.